# Extracting Random effects from nlme summary

Tags: r

I can extract Fixed effects from the nlme summary using `summary(fm1)`. But struggling how to get `Random effects:` portion.

```
fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, Orthodont, random = ~ age | Subject)
summary(fm1)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: Orthodont 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  454.6367 470.6173 -221.3183

Random effects:
 Formula: ~age | Subject
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev    Corr  
(Intercept) 2.3270340 (Intr)
age         0.2264278 -0.609
Residual    1.3100397       

Fixed effects: distance ~ age 
                Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 16.761111 0.7752460 80 21.620377       0
age          0.660185 0.0712533 80  9.265333       0
 Correlation: 
    (Intr)
age -0.848

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-3.223106086 -0.493761144  0.007316631  0.472151121  3.916033210 

Number of Observations: 108
Number of Groups: 27
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `ranef(fm1)` to extract for each subject.

Updated to give code for extraction from summary table:

```
>VarCorr(fm1)
Subject = pdLogChol(age) 
            Variance   StdDev    Corr  
(Intercept) 5.41508758 2.3270341 (Intr)
age         0.05126955 0.2264278 -0.609
Residual    1.71620400 1.3100397  

> temp <- VarCorr(fm1)
> temp[,2]
(Intercept)         age    Residual 
"2.3270341" "0.2264278" "1.3100397" 

> temp[1,2]
[1] "2.3270341"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `ranef` gives random effects but StdDev portion from `Random Effects:` from `summary(fm1)`.

Comment: Nice. I was following the print/summary path for lme object, but got lost at `print.modelStruct`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate feedback on my answers as it helps me give better ones in future. :)